# Gone Fission - Food for thought

Tags: riddle, word

This might, perhaps, be too easy, but this is my first riddle to post here.

> Get Copernicus and cut him in half for the start
>   Divide the start by two and you've got one extra.
>   Divide it by eight, instead, and you've got the last.
>   Put all three together for a yummy snack.

Comment: i don't think it's too easy :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The yummy snack is

> Bacon

Reason:

> Copernicus is the Chemical element. The atomic number is 112.
>  112 / 2 = 56 = Barium = **Ba**
>  56 / 2 - 1 = 27 = Cobalt = **Co**
>  56 / 8 = 7 = Nitro­gen = **N**

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I want to wait until you double-check your reasoning to mark it as such.  =D  (Partially my fault, because I had the logic for the 2nd word incorrect until seconds before your answer)

Comment: I changed the "-" to "+" yet. XD

Comment: Yep, but Copper is not Co

Comment: Yes, but Bacun doesn't exists. Just kidding ;) . So is it okay, if I change Copper to Cu and say that I have to choose the both letters in front of each word?

Comment: Double-check the clue:  "Divide the start by two and you've got one extra."  You had it right, the first time, by accident.  It could also be said that you have `one too many`.

Comment: What I mean is that copper plays no part in the riddle.

Comment: After a heavy laughing fit I recover myself. Now I got it. Thnx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36668/discussion-between-varon-and-khale-kitha).

Comment: Perfect =D  Nice job